# Force an update to a control that's bound to the InkCanvas

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I have the following XAML:

```
<Image Visibility="Visible" 
       Source="{Binding ElementName=inkCanvas, 
                        Converter={StaticResource InkCanvasToImageSource}, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</Image>

<InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" />
```

What I'm trying to do is to convert the InkCanvas Stroke Collection into a BitmapImage.  I'm using MVVM, and want to do this on a command.  The problem that I have is that the above code will not trigger the converter to fire.  I'm using UWP, so I can only pass one of the controls as a command parameter.

I need a method to convert from one to the other, but I'd like to do it inside the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `InkCanvas` control is associated with an instance of an [`InkPresenter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.inking.inkpresenter.aspx) object (exposed through the [`InkPresenter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.inkcanvas.inkpresenter.aspx) property). The `InkPresenter` provides properties, methods, and events for managing the input, processing, and rendering of ink data for an `InkCanvas` control. So binding to `InkCanvas` won't trigger your converter to fire as the ink input is managed entirely by the `InkPresenter`. And `InkCanvas.InkPresenter` property is not a dependency property, we can't bind to this property. So we can't force the `Image` update with bingding to `InkCanvas`. We have to do it in code-behind and this may break the MVVM design.

To update the `Image`, we can use `StrokesCollected` and `StrokesErased` event to detect ink input and in these event save all `InkStroke` objects to a `BitmapImage`. For example:

In the XAML

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image x:Name="MyImage" />
    <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
        <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    ...
    inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokesCollected += InkPresenter_StrokesCollected;
    inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokesErased += InkPresenter_StrokesErased;
}

private async void InkPresenter_StrokesErased(InkPresenter sender, InkStrokesErasedEventArgs args)
{
    var image = await SaveAsync();
    MyImage.Source = image;
}

private async void InkPresenter_StrokesCollected(InkPresenter sender, InkStrokesCollectedEventArgs args)
{
    var image = await SaveAsync();
    MyImage.Source = image;
}

private async Task<BitmapImage> SaveAsync()
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

    if (inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes().Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                await inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(stream);
                stream.Seek(0);
                bitmap.SetSource(stream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Here I just set the image to `MyImage`, you can also set it to your ViewModel and use `Binding` in the `Image`.